# How to fetch only immediate categories of a category in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I only expect to fetch the direct children to the parent category. But instead I get all the children to that category by using `getAllSubcategories` method of `DefaultCategoryService` class.

Example: Say I have categories "Men" which has subcategories pants and tops. And tops has subcategories t-shirt and sweaters. Then when on the Men category I would expect to see only pants and tops. But what I am seeing in the latest hybris is all categories(pants, tops, t-shirt, sweaters etc. ) when clicking on Men.

Could someone please guide how to achieve that ? Or Do i need to write a flexible Query?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the direct children, you can make use of `getCategories()` on the category object model. This will only give you the direct children of that specific category

Where you are now calling `getAllSubcategoriesForCategory(category)`, you can just go for `category.getCategories()`

Answer (score 0):

Hi There is no OOB method to give you only immediate subcategories but yes we can use the above  solution described by @Yoni

So you can create a simple method like this and use it when required.

```
  @Override
public List<CategoryData> getSubCategories(final String categoryCode)
{
    final CategoryModel category = defaultCategoryService.getCategoryForCode(categoryCode);
    if (category == null)
    {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    final Collection<CategoryModel> subCategories = category.getCategories();
    return categoryConverter.convertAll(subCategories );
}
```